# How to avoid reading stale data in MongoDB transactions?

Tags: mongodb, transactions

According to the [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions-production-consideration/#in-progress-transactions-and-stale-reads):

> Read operations inside a transaction can return stale data. That is, read operations inside a transaction are not guaranteed to see writes performed by other committed transactions or non-transactional writes. For example, consider the following sequence: 1) a transaction is in-progress 2) a write outside the transaction deletes a document 3) a read operation inside the transaction is able to read the now-deleted document since the operation is using a snapshot from before the write.

This can be illustrated with the following code example:

```js
import m from "mongodb";

const client = new m.MongoClient("mongodb-replicaset-uri");

await client.connect();

const coll = client.db("foo").collection("foo");

// Let's clear the collection in case someone actually decides to
// run this code, and does it more than once...
await coll.deleteMany();

const session = client.startSession();

const insertResult = await coll.insertOne({ xyz: 1 });

console.log(`inserted document with id ${insertResult.insertedId}`);

try {
  await session.withTransaction(async () => {
    // TOGGLE LINE
    // just a random read operation with a session reference
    // even though it's just a read operation, its presence
    // alters the behavior of the program 
    await coll.findOne({}, { session }); // toggle line

    // A delete operation that happens _outside_ of the transaction
    await coll.deleteOne({
      _id: insertResult.insertedId,
    });

    // This statement prints 1 if TOGGLE LINE is enabled, and 0 if commented out!
    console.log(await coll.countDocuments({}, { session }));
    // This statement prints 0 always
    console.log(await coll.countDocuments());
  });
} finally {
  await session.endSession();
  await client.close();
}
```

The behavior of the code above is explained by the quote from the docs. Apparently, as soon as an operation is executed within a transaction, some kind of DB snapshot is created, which is then used by all following transaction operations - the operations are "using a snapshot from before".

I have three questions.

1. Why is the snapshot not created as soon as the transaction is started (`withTransaction` is invoked) and instead postponed until the first transaction operation is executed? Is this for performance reasons, in case I execute an empty transaction?
2. Why are snapshots required? I sort of understand but I am still wondering whether it's not possible to implement transactions without them?
3. Is there a way to force transaction operations to see updates made outside of the transaction? I did try various read concerns, that did not have any influence.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the snapshot not created as soon as the transaction is started (`withTransaction` is invoked) and instead postponed until the first transaction operation is executed? Is this for performance reasons, in case I execute an empty transaction?

That is probably a reason. Another reason could be that you want your snapshot to be as updated as possible. If this actions occur:

1. Transaction is created
2. non-transactional update on document A
3. transactional update on document A

The transaction would abort in case the snapshot is created at step 1 (because of write-conflict). Instead, you want to avoid the abort, and you can do it by postponing the snapshot creation as long as possible. This makes sense because the concurrency control chosen is the optimistic one.

> Why are snapshots required? I sort of understand but I am still wondering whether it's not possible to implement transactions without them?

Implementing transactions with snapshots is a good solution to provide the *snapshot* isolation level. The *snapshot* isolation level is usually implemented using the MVCC, and the MongoDB snapshot makes the MVCC possible thanks to [how the WiredTiger cache works](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/tree/main/doc#wiredtiger-cache).

> Is there a way to force transaction operations to see updates made outside of the transaction? I did try various read concerns, that did not have any influence.

*Read concerns* operate on what data you read when the snapshot is created. You cannot see updates made outside of the transaction because it goes against the concept of transaction itself, which should be atomic. on the contrary, you want to avoid non-repeatable reads, that is why the (only available) isolation level is [snapshot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation) in MongoDB.

If you have other doubts, I suggest you to read [this document](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/tree/main/doc#mongodb-transactions). I wrote it a few years ago, but I am quite sure that 90% of it is still valid.